# How do you split using re.split as more of a "slice at" function?

Tags: python, regex, split

How do you split using re.split as more of a "slice at" function?

I know a good amount of regex functions, so that's not the issue. The issue is that, when using the split function, it removes whatever it searches for, unless it's in a group, but that causes it's own problems. I need it to split at NAME, TAKE SEL, or TAKE, but keep everything.

Here's the text:

```
NAME "440 Sine Wave 5 seconds.wav"
VOLPAN 1.000000 0.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
SOFFS 0.00000000000000
PLAYRATE 1.00000000000000 1 0.00000000000000 -1 0 0.002500
CHANMODE 0
GUID {857A4ED4-172A-43EE-AECF-CC4D027CE5D3}
<SOURCE WAVE
FILE "C:\Users\Greg\Desktop\test2\440 Sine Wave 5 seconds.wav"
>
SM 0.607738664073 0.6077386641 + 2.044211870063 2.0442118701 + 3.314938167670 3.3149381677 + 4.088423740126 4.0884237401
TAKE SEL
NAME "440 Sine Wave 5 seconds render 002.wav"
TAKEVOLPAN 0.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
SOFFS 0.00000000000000
PLAYRATE 1.00000000000000 1 0.00000000000000 -1 0 0.002500
CHANMODE 0
GUID {DD233FDE-7641-4F02-AE9A-8B99FF400F24}
<SOURCE WAVE
FILE "C:\Users\Greg\Documents\REAPER Media\440 Sine Wave 5 seconds render 002.wav"
>
SM 0.899258786122 0.8992587861 + 1.268694185507 1.2686941855 + 1.709174854005 1.7091748540 + 2.050192145745 2.0501921457 + 2.718017675403 2.7180176754 + 3.307693409037 3.3076934090 + 3.762383131357 3.7623831314 + 4.131818530742 4.1318185307 + 4.458626768660 4.4586267687
TAKE
NAME "440 Sine Wave 5 seconds render 003.wav"
TAKEVOLPAN 0.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
SOFFS 0.00000000000000
PLAYRATE 1.00000000000000 1 0.00000000000000 -1 0 0.002500
CHANMODE 0
GUID {A01A4793-7E2C-47EC-A22C-659A8FE0C162}
<SOURCE WAVE
FILE "C:\Users\Greg\Documents\REAPER Media\440 Sine Wave 5 seconds render 003.wav"
>
SM 0.679018451873 0.6790184519 + 2.874317267450 2.8743172675
>
```

Here's how it would be split

```
NAME "440 Sine Wave 5 seconds.wav"
VOLPAN 1.000000 0.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
SOFFS 0.00000000000000
PLAYRATE 1.00000000000000 1 0.00000000000000 -1 0 0.002500
CHANMODE 0
GUID {857A4ED4-172A-43EE-AECF-CC4D027CE5D3}
<SOURCE WAVE
FILE "C:\Users\Greg\Desktop\test2\440 Sine Wave 5 seconds.wav"
>
SM 0.607738664073 0.6077386641 + 2.044211870063 2.0442118701 + 3.314938167670 3.3149381677 + 4.088423740126 4.0884237401

TAKE SEL
NAME "440 Sine Wave 5 seconds render 002.wav"
TAKEVOLPAN 0.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
SOFFS 0.00000000000000
PLAYRATE 1.00000000000000 1 0.00000000000000 -1 0 0.002500
CHANMODE 0
GUID {DD233FDE-7641-4F02-AE9A-8B99FF400F24}
<SOURCE WAVE
FILE "C:\Users\Greg\Documents\REAPER Media\440 Sine Wave 5 seconds render 002.wav"
>
SM 0.899258786122 0.8992587861 + 1.268694185507 1.2686941855 + 1.709174854005 1.7091748540 + 2.050192145745 2.0501921457 + 2.718017675403 2.7180176754 + 3.307693409037 3.3076934090 + 3.762383131357 3.7623831314 + 4.131818530742 4.1318185307 + 4.458626768660 4.4586267687

TAKE
NAME "440 Sine Wave 5 seconds render 003.wav"
TAKEVOLPAN 0.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
SOFFS 0.00000000000000
PLAYRATE 1.00000000000000 1 0.00000000000000 -1 0 0.002500
CHANMODE 0
GUID {A01A4793-7E2C-47EC-A22C-659A8FE0C162}
<SOURCE WAVE
FILE "C:\Users\Greg\Documents\REAPER Media\440 Sine Wave 5 seconds render 003.wav"
>
SM 0.679018451873 0.6790184519 + 2.874317267450 2.8743172675
>
```

Comment: I don't get it. Is there even a difference? Could you perhaps point it out?

Comment: Isn't this information important enough to parse it on the fly instead of breaking it up first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a lookahead to perform the split just before each of those tokens, but you cannot split on a zero-length match so you have to match something.  In this case it looks like you should just be able to split on the newline before the token.

As for the regular expression to do this, based on your example it looks like you only want to split on `NAME` if it is not preceeded by `TAKE` or `TAKE SEL`, which makes it a little more complicated.  The following should work:

```
re.split(r'\n(?=TAKE(?: SEL)?\n|(?<!\nTAKE\n)(?<!\nTAKE SEL\n)NAME)', s)
```

So the idea here is that we will match a newline if the next line is `TAKE` or `TAKE SEL`, or if the next line starts with `NAME` and the previous line was not `TAKE` or `TAKE SEL`.

Examples:

```
>>> s = 'foo\nTAKE\nbar'   # split on TAKE
>>> re.split(r'\n(?=TAKE(?: SEL)?\n|(?<!\nTAKE\n)(?<!\nTAKE SEL\n)NAME)', s)
['foo', 'TAKE\nbar']
>>> s = 'foo\nTAKE SEL\nbar'   # split on TAKE SEL
>>> re.split(r'\n(?=TAKE(?: SEL)?\n|(?<!\nTAKE\n)(?<!\nTAKE SEL\n)NAME)', s)
['foo', 'TAKE SEL\nbar']
>>> s = 'foo\nTAKE SEL\nNAME\nbar'   # split on TAKE SEL but not on NAME
>>> re.split(r'\n(?=TAKE(?: SEL)?\n|(?<!\nTAKE\n)(?<!\nTAKE SEL\n)NAME)', s)
['foo', 'TAKE SEL\nNAME\nbar']
>>> s = 'foo\nNAME\nbar'   # split on NAME since no TAKE or TAKE SEL before
>>> re.split(r'\n(?=TAKE(?: SEL)?\n|(?<!\nTAKE\n)(?<!\nTAKE SEL\n)NAME)', s)
['foo', 'NAME\nbar']
```

Comment: AWESOOOOM! I'll have to study this a bit to understand some of that regex. Thank you sooo much, spent hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: So is this what the regex is saying?
\n could be followed by:
TAKE\nNAME or \nTAKE\sSEL\nNAME or NAME (but only if NAME is not in front of TAKE or TAKE SEL)

Comment: Another question, I thought when using r \n becomes a literal "\n" and not a newline character. So what is r really doing here?

Comment: You interpretation of what the regex does is correct, regarding the `r` prefix on the string, the literal characters `\n` are interpreted as a newline by the regex engine, so `r'\n'` and `'\n'` will have the same behavior in Python regex.  But you should always used raw string literals with regular expressions because it makes all of the other escapes much easier to read.